# Iterating through dict and applying multiple methods to each value

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to take the values of a dictionary apply a method to each value then have those new values added to a different dictionary. Something like:

```
d = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c'}

def somefunction(d):
    for value in d:
        value.somemethod
        value.anothermethod
        value.onemoremethod
        newdict = {0:value(result value of all 3 methods applied concanated together, 1:value(result value of all 3 methods applied concanated together), 2:value(you get the idea)
```

The type of the dict values are `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>` and I want to apply the `.contents[]` method to each value and save them as new values to a new dict.

Comment: Are you not supposed to *call* these methods?

Comment: So the result should be a dictionary containing the original keys that map to *three-tuples*? The output of the three methods?

Comment: What do you mean by the results concatenated together?

Comment: The values are snippets of html code I want to parse each snippet with bs4 and extract the title, description etc tags and pull out the text from them then save that to a new value in a new dict so that i'll have the relevant text for each article saved as a value in a dict to be reference to later. That's what i mean by concatenate the results. The 2 answers below solved my problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *dictionary comprehension* for this:

```
newdict = {k: (v.somemethod(),v.anothermethod(),v.onemoremethod())
           for k,v d.items()}
```

So here you construct a new dictionary where the original keys map on 3-tuples that contain the output of the three method calls on that value.

For instance if the methods are `.isdigit()`, `.isalpha()` and `.upper()` the result will be:

```
>>> {k: (v.isdigit(),v.isalpha(),v.upper()) for k,v in d.items()}
{0: (False, True, 'A'), 1: (False, True, 'B'), 2: (False, True, 'C')}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you're trying to iterate through the dictionary is incorrect, and if you're trying to create a new dictionary from their results your want to add to it as you iterate and declare it outside of your loop.

If you're using Python 2.x, iterating through a dictionary is done with:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
  ...
```

and in 3.x with:

```
for key, value in d.items():
  ...
```

If my understanding of what you want the results to be, you should do something along the lines of:

```
newDict = {k: '{}{}{}'.format(v.somemethod(), v.anothermethod(), v.onemoremethod()) for k, v in d.items()}
```

in order to have the resulting values of each method concatenated together as a single value for the key.